# System is slow after upgrading to 4 GB RAM

Tags: windows, memory, performance

Why would my computer run smoother with 2 GB rather than 4 GB of RAM? Recently I purchased a new set of 2 x 2 GB from HP.

Now I am running Windows 7 64-bit and it can map all 4 GB of RAM, but it runs not too well. It's not smooth, programs take longer to load, video is choppy and it's just all around worse. The moment I take out 2GB stick out of my Intel motherboard it runs great again.

How can I fix this problem? I have ran the Windows Mem Test, it rebooted and scanned 2 of 2 and came up with no problems.

Specs:

- HP ProBook E-series 4530S
- Intel Core i5
- 2 x 2 GB
- Radeon graphics

Comment: Are your RAMs both the same model? same brand and same speed?

Comment: Did you purchase DDR3 SDRAM, 1333 MHz modules? The HP spec sheet for this state "Maximized dual-channel performance requires SODIMMs of the same size and speed in both memory slots". Compatibility might be an issue here.

Comment: Have you tried swapping them?  reverse the position of the ram, if it doesn't get better, then it's likely an issue of compatibility between that particular brand of ram and your hardware.  If it does get better, than maybe you have a flaky dimm.

Comment: There is a BIOS update available in March of this year. Have you tried updating that yet?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've mismatched your RAM, to me. Have you tried it with just the two new sticks?

Either way, please post the full specs (i.e. speed) of all 4 modules.

Comment: *Recently I purchased a new set of 2 x 2 GB from HP* and *it can map all 4 GB of RAM* sounds like the OP is using just the new (matching) sticks.

Comment: This notebook only has two slots. So, they can only use the two new ones.

Comment: @Dennis You're totally right, my misunderstanding